# Dumb Linux SNMP question

Tags: linux, system-administration, snmp

I'm running Ubuntu and have snmpd running.  I can do an snmpwalk:

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 1 localhost .1
```

and I get back about 20 values (SNMPv2-MIB -- mostly system description/name/uptime stuff).

Where are the memory, disk and network values?  I've tried querying specific OIDs that I found Googling and they're not found.

I assume I have to enable memory/disk/network/etc somehow but can't figure out how (I've spent a lot of time Googling -- apparently this question is so noobish that no one else has asked it???).

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Voting to close, very hard to consider this programming-related at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

```
com2sec paranoid default public
#com2sec readonly default public
#com2sec readwrite default private
```

part to:

```
#com2sec paranoid default public
com2sec readonly 127.0.0.1 public
#com2sec readwrite default private
```

Restart snmpd:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd restart
```

Then try this one:

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 2c 127.0.0.1 .
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's using snmpd, check the config file: /etc/snmpd/snmpd.conf

SNMPD supports more limited monitoring like a disk usage threshold. There might be more options, I haven't monitored machines with it a lot.

Apparently you can also use the setup program:

```
snmpconf -g basic_setup
```

It will prompt you for information and configure the system for you.

Good luck.